# How to fill missing data set from Matlab or Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, neural-network, missing-data

I got a data set (daily and monthly rainfall data) but it is missing so much value.
In order to training the data i need to fill up the missing data, can you tell me how can I do it? I used with SPSS Statistic but seem the values not good or maybe i did wrong methods.

```
sample:
Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
3    3    5    5   6    7   8    7    8    9   NaN   4
NaN  3    NaN  5   NaN  3   4    NaN  4    6   7     8
7    NaN  4    7   8    9   4    2    NaN  4   6     5
.....................................................
```

Another question is that, mostly the data before training should be normalized data, is this correct? 
Thank you for your answering !
Merry Christmas all !

Comment: You might want to look into the MATLAB curve fitting toolbox.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us your code, maybe it's only a minor error.

Answer (score 1):

For missing data, you may choose to take the `mean` of existing data to mimic the lost data. For example, You take `mean(3, 7) = 5` to fill up the `NaN` in `Jan` and so on. I think this is probably the easiest way. You might also consider matrix factorization and curve fitting.

For normalization, some classifiers don't require normalized data. However, having data normalized is usually a good practice to improve performance. For neural network, it is known that normalized data is much favoured. So don't hesitate to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Ctrl+G`, then click on `Special`, then check `Formulas`, then make sure only `Errors` is checked, then click `OK`. This will select all the cells with errors. Then you can press `Delete` to clear their content.

I sometimes create a second table with formulas converting the values of one table into either the original value or something easier to manage, as suggested [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hide-error-values-and-error-indicators-in-cells-HP003056121.aspx).